# Switch cases for multiple values?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Is it possible to use switch cases to compare multiple values? I am trying to output a barcode for each number but I do not know it this is possible to do with switch cases. If it is not is there an easier way to do it? I've been stuck on this one a lot. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int zipcode(int);
int correctiondigit(int);
int barcode(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

int zipcode(int hold) {

    cout << hold << endl;

    return hold;
}

void extractor(int zip) {

    int five = zip % 10;
    int four = zip % 100 / 10;
    int three = zip % 1000 / 100;       
    int two = zip % 10000 / 1000;
    int one = zip % 100000 / 10000;

    cout << one << " " << two << " " << three << " " << four << " " << five << endl;
}

int correctiondigit(int zip) {

    int five = zip % 10;
    int four = zip % 100 / 10;
    int three = zip % 1000 / 100;
    int two = zip % 10000 / 1000;
    int one = zip % 100000 / 10000;

    int cdigit = one + two + three + four + five;

    if (cdigit < 10){
        cdigit = 10 - cdigit;
    }
    else if (cdigit < 20) {
        cdigit = 20 - cdigit;
    }
    else if (cdigit < 30) {
        cdigit = 30 - cdigit;
    }
    else if (cdigit < 40) {
        cdigit = 40 - cdigit;
    }
    else if (cdigit < 50) {
        cdigit = 50 - cdigit;
    }

    cout << "Your correction digit is: " << cdigit << endl;

    barcode(cdigit, one, two, three, four, five, cdigit);

    return cdigit;
}
```

can I do switch cases like switch (digit, one, two....) and so on?

```
int barcode(int digit, int one , int two, int three, int four, int five, int repeat) {

    switch (digit)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << ":::||";
        break;
    case 2 :
        cout << "::|:|";
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "4489494";
        break;
    }

    return digit;
}

int main() {

    int zip = int();
    int gather = int();


    cout << "Please enter your zip code: " << endl;
    cin >> zip;

    gather = zipcode(zip);
    extractor(zip);
    correctiondigit(zip);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: If you encounter naming variables like `oneX`, `twoX`, `nX` that's a high indicator you should organize your data in an array (e.g. a `std::vector`), and use a loop to process it.

Comment: No, it is not possible to use a switch to check values of multiple variables.   The `switch(expr)` accepts a single expression that has a result of integral type.   Although it is not the question you asked, as user0042 noted, you need to restructure your code to use a container and loop over elements of that container.